# Array Modifier Causing Objects To Become Hollow in Blender 2.8

Tags: modifiers

I am new to blender and trying to model out this grid object, then trying to cut a bevel into the side with a boolean modifier. The problem I'm having (which I cannot find an answer to anywhere online) is after using the array modifier the object suddenly is hollow.

I've included this [.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eh3M3SUiq3yj3N3ac9fiGLyGteETiwnJ) and in it you can see the object before the array with the boolean cut perfectly removed, still keeping the faces of the object and not being hollow.

Like this:
[image: Clean cuts, faces intact.]

The arrayed object, however, has no faces where the cut has happened and is also causing weird distortions on each corner where the boolean modifier overlaps.

Like such:
[image: Cut edges, empty]

Any suggestions or knowledge would be much appreciated! Also, if you have any suggestions to a better way to accomplish what I'm after I'm open to that too, thanks!

Comment: Hi, trying to understand here. Maybe you have an example with the modifiers not yet applied? I have no idea how you went from the object to the grid. It's not even the same height, so it's hard to figure it out

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response and thanks for the help. The small object was just to show the example off. I initially created a square, booleaned out the middle to hollow it out, then arrayed once across to get one row, then once again to get the remaining rows. After that, I then created a long rectangle, booleaned out the curve from it using a pillar or whatever. Then I used that rectangle with the inside cut out to boolean the edges from the main object.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is you have a lot of overlapping geometry, there will always be distortions when faces occupy the same space, this is aslo probably why your boolean modifier isn't behaving as it should.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding: when I use the array modifier to create the grid, since I'm overlapping the squares in the array then it's causing it to become hollow?